# How to make Windows interpret a drag as a click?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, windows-registry

My mother has motor function impairment in her hands, which makes it difficult to use the mouse correctly. The main problem is that when she clicks something, **she moves at the same time, in effect registering a drag event** instead of a click.

I already tried, without success:

- changing the mouse settings
- using SteadyMouse at various settings
- using a trackball (my mom cannot understand how to use it)
- using the keyboard (too complex and memory intensive)
- training my mom on releasing the mouse button quickly (she has memory issues too, so she forgets)

Is there any way to edit the Registry or something so that any drag event would register as a click? She never needs the drag event anyway.

Thanks for any pointers. BTW, this is on Windows 10.

Comment: The faster the mouse speed is, the quicker it is registered as a drag. Setting a slower speed is often an easy fix for this kind of problem. Mouse accelleration can be used in order to aid in using the mouse better too, but also replacing the mouse itself can help. A more heavy mouse will be less prone to click and move, but also a differently shaped mouse can aid in it. Usually larger mouses are easier for this kind of behavior.

Comment: Thanks LPChip! I will look into a one button mouse too, and slow down the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If just using the keyboard would be easier, then here are some alternatives:

First, Windows has this functionality built in.  It is called Mouse Keys.  You can read how to implement it [here](https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/windows-10-using-your-keyboard-control-mouse).

Secondly, if you dont have a full size keyboard or want to use a different key, you can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to assign a mouse click to any key you choose.  The script would be super simple.  The example below assigns the <kbd>F12</kbd> key to the left mouse click:

```
F12::Click
```

Lastly, with a little ingenuity, a minor amount of electronics knowledge and soldering, you could make your own big, separate mouse button.  Use a spare mouse or purchase the cheapest mouse you can find and disassemble it.  Find the electrical contacts for the left mouse button and solder it to large momentary push button like [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=large%20momentary%20push%20button&sxsrf=ALeKk02ICX9ZCbAUEllKjbLEhFV_4nD0pw:1607574361808&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig6aOWycLtAhWCylkKHTqaAksQ_AUoAXoECBAQAw&biw=1280&bih=578).  Then assemble them into a box, leaving just the button accessible.  Attach the USB cord to your PC and viola: A single large mouse button.  In case you were wondering, yes, you can attach as many mice to your computer as you want and they all can control the single mouse pointer and its actions.  This might sound intimidating, but it is actually very easy.

Comment: Thanks for these ideas but I'm afraid my mom is tool old and memory-impaired to learn keyboard alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small program called X-mouse Button Control which you can get [here](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) it is even available as a portable software, and it can also run at windows start. This allows you to change pretty much every mouse behavior, and i do believe you can also change the behavior of click drag. Hope that helps! I have it on my home computer, so I might try it tonight and see if I can actually get it to work like you want to

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the program and tried various settings but could not get the result I need. From what I understand, it offers great versatility in changing what the buttons do, but cannot "remap" actions, so to speak. I'm still looking for solutions.

Comment: Wow, I honestly thought the program had that function, I am sorry it did not provide the result you needed. Hope you find it eventually